# Display photos from Flickr on a JSP page based on tag

Tags: jsp, flickr

I am currently doing a project using JSP, where a user can give preference of pictures they want to view when they open the page (example - nature, park, ocean, computers etc.) So, I want to import photos from Flickr based on those tags and display on the homepage when the user logs in. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the documentation of the [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/).  This page catalogs all the services that you can call, and links to toolkits for various programming environments.

Depending on your needs, you may or may not require user authentication.  For my project, I used the [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) library to manage the OAuth authentication protocol.

Comment: Yes, I went through them. I have zeroed on "flickr.photos.search"